# Как управлять расширениями (selenium)?

Tags: python, selenium

У меня есть скрипт который работает с selenium, в середине программы у меня открывается расширение по моему нажатию, как мне управлять расширением и нажать куда-либо в нем?
Если не с помощью selenium`а то с помощью чего?

Answer (score 0):

Расширение - это обычная вкладка браузера, перед переключением на эту вкладку надо поставить паузу хотя бы в 1 секунду